# Spring Boot Resilience4J Circuit Breaker(fallback method)

Tags: spring-boot, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

I don't have clearly understand how the fallback method works.
For example:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FHyv.png)
Will this method be executed after each error in the callee method or just when the circuit breaker will be closed?

Answer (score 2):

It's like a try/catch, but after the CircuitBreaker has recorded success/failure.
If you use `Exception` in your fallback method signature, it catches all Exceptions. But you can narrow down the scope to `CallNotPermittedException`, if you only want to execute the fallback method when the CircuitBreaker is open.

Comment: If I in fallback method will get successfully value from the cache. Does the count of errors in slide window will still increase?

Comment: Yes, since the fallback method is executed after the CircuitBreaker has recorded a failure.

Comment: @RobertWinkler
please help me 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68407909/using-circuit-breaker-in-spring-boot